# How to fix "AssertionError: keyType should be DataType" error

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

JSON byte data streaming from Kafka-console-producer 
PySpark - has a parser json data to dataframe.

I have tried to parse this json by using given schema.But it gives me an error about "AssertionError: keyType should be DataType"
What do I need to do to parse json with custom schema?

```
schema = StructType()\
    .add("contact_id", LongType())\
    .add("first_name", StringType())\
    .add("last_name", StringType())\
    .add("contact_number", MapType(StringType,
                                   StructType()
                                   .add("home", LongType())
                                   .add("contry_code", StringType())))
```

Expecting this format JSON Data: 
{"contact_id":"23","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","contact_number":{"home":4564564567,"country_code":"+1"}}

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. This should be the correct schema definition.

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('contactId', LongType(), True),
    StructField('firstName', StringType(), True),
    StructField('lastName', StringType(), True),
    StructField("contactNumber", ArrayType(
        StructType([
                StructField("type", StringType(), True),
                StructField("number", LongType(), True),
                StructField("countryCode", StringType(), True)
            ])
        ), True)
    ])
```